# Save all AJAX JSON data to file using Fiddler2

Tags: ajax, json, decode, fiddler

I want to save to a file, all the data returned from multiple AJAX requests. The requests are of the same format. And AJAX is using JSON (which encodes text in UTF-8).

I'm trying out "Fiddler Web Debugger" and I've added a filter to show only the AJAX sessions and in the Inspectors-bottom window I can see the returned text that I'm interested in. To view this text in this bottom window I can either select the 'JSON' button or the 'Text' button and then press the "Response is encoded and may need to be decoded" button.

I then tried Menu > File > Save > Save all sessions. This looks like it might be saving what I need but I cant really tell as most of the text is gobbldy gook (just the headers are intelligible).

Is this the best way to save data returned from multiple requests?
Is there some way to translate the gobbledy gook? (I'm guessing the problem has something to do with the UTF-8 encoding).
Ideally the file would show a list of JSON string - one for each returned text. Though, if not, I can parse it to extract the data I need. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UTF-8 encoding is effectively the same as ASCII for most western languages. It sounds more likely that the server is GZIP-compressing the response content which is why it would be binary gibberish instead of plaintext. You can direct Fiddler to automatically decompress and unchunk all responses using the **AutoDecode** button on the toolbar.

Fiddler offers *many* different export formats, depending on what your end goal is. You can save in a "lossless" Session Archive Zip (SAZ) format if you plan to reload the content into Fiddler. Or, you can use the options shown by the File > Export command to export in many other formats. Or, you can write a bit of script (Rules > Customize Rules) to export the content in any way you'd like.

Comment: Thanks @EricLaw-msft. This one works: Menu > File > Export Sessions > All Sessions > Raw Files